# How to go back to "All Artists" in iTunes

Tags: itunes, keyboard

In iTunes, in Artists view, after I've used <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to go to the track currently playing, how do I exit and go back to showing All Artists? I currently have to scroll to the top of the Artists list (on the sidebar) and click "All Artists" every time. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know short of scrolling with the mouse is, after having pressed <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, you can press the following key sequence to get to **All Artists**: <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>

This assumes you have an artist's name starting with the letter **A**. If not, then substitute **A** with the first character of the artist's name that's directly under **Compilations** in the sidebar.

In other words, after having pressed <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice sets focus to the now playing artist in the sidebar. If it's not the artist directly under **Compilations** then pressing the appropriate key to get there plus <kbd>↑</kbd> twice takes you back to **All Artists**.

Comment: Please don't put keystrokes both in the `<kbd>` tags as well as typing them out normally - it makes your answer harder to read and is redundant.

Comment: @tubedogg thank you for your edits and feedback.  I have removed the `<code>` tags however I put back the dash between the keyboard shortcuts because that is the default method Apple uses in their documentation as in: [OS X: Keyboard shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)